# (webassembly) transfert many variables from code C to javascript

Tags: webassembly

I have function in my code C where several variables change and I want to pass this change to javascript after I covert my code C to wasm.
I see in the Internet that CCALL and CWRAP can do that for one variable not for several in the same time 
How can I export many variables in the same time ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to return multiple variables by a single function call, you can't.

WebAssembly spec does not yet have [multi-return](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/937) and C itself does not have multi-return (neither JS doesn't).

However, you have some options to achieve similar goal:

1. Just call multiple functions (I mean, why not?)
2. Define a C struct and pass its pointer to JS.
3. [Define WebIDL](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/WebIDL-Binder.html#pointers-references-value-types-ref-and-value) for C struct to interface with JS easily.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I will choose between the 2 latest options of your response and now i read the documentations to understand how to solve my problem with one of them.